# How to read all approved items from Facebook with Flask

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, flask

Given both `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and `FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET`, what sound I change in the following code (or even on the FB control panel) so as to be able to read `email`, `public_profile` and `user_friends` of a user (me)?

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request
from flask_oauth import OAuth

SECRET_KEY = ''
DEBUG = True
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = ''
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = ''

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = DEBUG
app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY
oauth = OAuth()

facebook = oauth.remote_app('facebook',
    base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_url='/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
    consumer_key=FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    consumer_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    request_token_params={'scope': ["email", "public_profile", "user_friends"]}
)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return facebook.authorize(callback=url_for('facebook_authorized',
        next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None,
        _external=True))

@app.route('/login/authorized')
@facebook.authorized_handler
def facebook_authorized(resp):
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason=%s error=%s' % (
            request.args['error_reason'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )
    session['oauth_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    me = facebook.get('/me')
    return 'type %s, data %s, headers %s, raw_data %s, status %s' % (type(me), str(me.data), str(me.headers), str(me.raw_data), str(me.status))

@facebook.tokengetter
def get_facebook_oauth_token():
    return session.get('oauth_token')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**EDIT:**

```
request_token_params={'scope': 'public_profile,user_friends,email'}

me = facebook.get('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,gender,locale,timezone,updated_time,verified,friends,email')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using v2.4 of the Graph API, you'll need to specify all the fields you want returned at

```
me = facebook.get('/me?fields=id,name,gender,email,friends')
```

etc. It's all in the docs.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fields

Comment: You need to be more specific. What doesn't work exactly? Also, you only specified `email` as scope parameter, `public_profile` and `user_friends` are missing. You cannot get data for the latter if you don't request the permissions

Comment: Sure. I updated the `scope`. Not sure if this is what you meant though. Can you please have a look? In addition, the response returns `status` `200` and as far as I can see the `facebook-api-version` is `v2.4`. So what's wrong then?

Comment: I meant what the actual problem is. And no, I can't decide from your code what is wrong (if there's somehting wrong). Stackoverflow is no debugging service. We can only give you valid hints... Still, you'll need to request each field as I already wrote in my answer. I don't see this in your code.

Comment: I set `request_token_params` to `{'scope': ["email", "public_profile", "user_friends"]}` from `{'scope': "email"}`. `request_token_params` is an argument of function `oauth.remote_app`. Isn't this what you suggested?

Comment: Read my answer! How hard can this be? Additionally, I said you need to set the correct scopes, but that was in my comment

Comment: ok. I read them carefully and after a lot of trial and error I made two edits (see `EDIT` on my initial question). Everything works fine now. I am able to retrieve all permitted fields except for the list of friends - although I can read the total number of them. In fact, I get something like this: `u'friends': {u'data': [], u'summary': {u'total_count': 323}}` Any ideas how to read the friends themselves as well?

Comment: You can only get those friends which also use your app. Probably none of your friends use your app then... This is the behavior since v2.0, meaning since 15 months... See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0 Quote: `The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.` If it helped, please accept my answer.